# Do differential operators on a manifold commute regardless the chart?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a real $n$ dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$, and a chart $\varphi:\mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, with $\mathcal{U}$ an open set inside $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In $\mathcal{U}$, I have the coordinate lines given by $\varphi^{-1}$ applied to the lines parallel to some coordinate-axis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e the sets $\lbrace(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n | \text{ only $x_i$ coordinate varies} \rbrace$. I'm interested in the set of operators on the smooth maps from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set $\mathcal{O} = \lbrace F:\mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{M}}(\text{smooth}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rbrace$

Using the chart, we build the operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \in \mathcal{O}$ .My question is: **Do these operators commute with each other (regardless the chart)?**. For example, if I were using the polar chart in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with $\mathcal{M}$ an open connected subset excluding the center), I would just *write* any map $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathcal{M}}(\text{smooth})$ as $f(r,\theta)$, ant therefore it would appear to be "obvious" that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r \partial \theta} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta \partial r}$, but I feel this is like *cheating*. Does this work the same way for any chart I would choose, no matter how *curved* it is (from the "non-curved" $x,y$ coordinate chart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as your manifold is sufficiently smooth (so that the charts are $C^2$), mixed partial derivatives of a (sufficiently) smooth function will always be equal. (The theorem from multivariable calculus tells you that this works fine whenever you have a $C^2$ function.)